# python and sqlite3 basic problem from cs50

Tags: python, sqlite, cs50

```
import csv

import sqlite3

open("shows.db", "w").close()
con = sqlite3.connect('shows.db')
db = con.cursor()


db.execute("CREATE TABLE shows (id INTEGER, title TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id))")
db.execute("CREATE TABLE genres (show_id INTEGER, genre TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(show_id) REFERENCES shows(id))")

with open("/Users/xxx/Downloads/CS50 2019 - Lecture 7 - Favorite TV Shows (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        title = row["title"].strip().upper()
        id = db.execute("INSERT INTO shows (title) VALUES(?)", (title,))
        for genre in row["genres"].split(", "):
             db.execute("INSERT INTO genres (show_id, genre) VALUES(?, ?)", id,genre)

con.commit()

con.close()
```

When I run this code I think in this line  `"db.execute("INSERT INTO genres (show_id, genre) VALUES(?, ?)", id,genre)"` the problem happens.

My console says

```
"db.execute("INSERT INTO genres (show_id, genre) VALUES(?, ?)", id,genre)
TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)"
```

I don't under stand why it says 3 given even though I gave two argument ( id, genre )

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BnuS.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep getting the error TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465681/keep-getting-the-error-typeerror-function-takes-at-most-2-arguments-3-given)

Comment: thta is python error, not a sql error, the METHOD `execute` received 3 arguments instead of 2. SQL arguments should be given in a `tuple`, not each argument separatly. You did well for the first INSERT, but not the second. `db.execute("INSERT INTO genres (show_id, genre) VALUES(?, ?)", (id,genre))`

Comment: I think you need to pass there (id, genre) as a tuple, it would be treated as a single argument. You are passing as separate arguments, now

Comment: I tried but here another error comes. `sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. ` Does it mean the id is not INTEGER type? But in my db, I looks like INTEGER( like 1,2,3, ... )

Comment: @syha682100 Don't you mind adding DB schema and point where do you get this error?

Comment: I added a link in my post. Left one is ID and the name of shows. and Right is the id of show(show_id) and genre.

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problems with code**

1. This line returns the cursor. In order to get the result, you will need to call terminal operations such as `.fetchall()`, `.fetchmany()` or `.fetchone()`

```
id = db.execute("INSERT INTO shows (title) VALUES(?)", (title,))
```

2. As you didn't call the terminal operator or print out the result, you wouldn't know that the `INSERT` operation returns `None`, not actual id
3. Minor: generally, it isn't advised to call variables the same name as built-in Python functions. See [id](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id).
4. As I suggested in the comment, you will need to insert a tuple:

```
db.execute(
    "INSERT INTO genres (show_id, genre) VALUES (?, ?)",
    (id_, genre)
)
```

**Solution**

You will need to select `title` from the `shows` table after insertion. Also, retrieve the id from the selection and then insert it into the `genres` table.

The simplified version of the code, to showcase how to do it:

```
import csv

import sqlite3

open("shows.db", "w").close()
con = sqlite3.connect('shows.db')
db = con.cursor()


db.execute("CREATE TABLE shows (id INTEGER, title TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id))")
db.execute("CREATE TABLE genres (show_id INTEGER, genre TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(show_id) REFERENCES shows(id))")


shows = ["FRIENS", "Game of Trhones", "Want", "Scooby Doo"]
genres = ["Comedy", "Fantasy", "Action", "Cartoon"]


for ind, show in enumerate(shows):
    db.execute("INSERT INTO shows (title) VALUES(?)", (show,))
    id_ = con.execute(
        "SELECT id FROM shows WHERE title = :show ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1",
        {
            "show": show
        },
    ).fetchone()
    db.execute(
        "INSERT INTO genres (show_id, genre) VALUES (?, ?)",
        (id_[0], genres[ind], )
    )

con.commit()

con.close()
```

For more details, check my code on the [GitHub](https://github.com/ChameleonTartu/so-answers/tree/main/so-67251557).

*`SELECT` statement may look a bit complex. What it does in a nutshell, it takes the matching title and returns the largest id. As titles may be the same, you always take the last inserted that matches.*

**General suggestions on debugging issues like that**

1. Try using print as much as possible
2. Use [dir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) and [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) functions to see methods and be able to google types
3. Search docs or examples on GitHub

Comment: Thank you ! It was very helpful. But can i ask you one more question? when I make a line like ```id = con.execute(~~~~~)``` It's not just containing the value of ```con.execute(~~~)``` in ```id``` but also executing the ```con.execute(~~~)``` ?

Comment: @syha682100 Yes, it sounds right. It is a so-called function with side-effect. 

Note: If you look at `SELECT` statement, you will see I have `fetchone()` in the end to return the result. This why you don't get object but the actual id.

Comment: If I just write a code like ```id = con.execute(~~~)``` without ```fetchone()``` then it just means that ```id``` points out just ```con.execute()``` ?

Comment: @syha682100, I think it returns `cursor`-object. You can print out the type and search in the sqlite3 docs to see what output would correspond to.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. If it is not too much to ask, it would be my last question. ```"SELECT id FROM shows WHERE title = :show ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1",
        {
            "show": show
        },
    ).fetchone()```. In this line, Does the first ```:show``` mean that this will use ```show``` by pointing out  ```"show": show``` which uses ```shows = ["FRIENS", "Game of Trhones", "Want", "Scooby Doo"]```? and if it is right, which show is which in ```"show":show``` ?

Comment: and why you use ```con.execute``` instead of ```db.execute``` in this line ```id_ = con.execute(
        "SELECT id FROM shows WHERE title = :show ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1",
        {
            "show": show
        },
    ).fetchone()```?

Comment: `db.execute` vs `con.execute` I think it is the same operation.

Comment: When it comes to my query, in query, everything that is prefixed with a semi-colon is a placeholder, when query substitutes values it looks for keys in the dictionary that are the same. :show in query corresponds to "show" in dictionary. When the show in the dictionary found, value got substituted in the finalized SQL query.

Comment: Thank you for your limitless knowledge even though I asked a lot 

Answer (score 0):

I can see your issue. It's because you're trying the add in the id and genre into the query like they do in the sqlite3 documentation. In the documentation they did what your trying to do in a tuple but you did it in the function call.

Try this instead:

```
sql_query = ("INSERT INTO genres (show_id, genre) VALUES(?, ?)", id, genre)
db.execute(sql_query)
```

Or you could put it into a one-liner:

```
# notice how there is 2 parenthesis
#          ↓                                                             ↓
db.execute(("INSERT INTO genres (show_id, genre) VALUES(?, ?)", id, genre))
#          ↑                                                             ↑
```

Comment: It seemed doesn't work. I just followed the lecture, https://youtu.be/Wb0DM9I8RDo?t=6846. I think the problem is that in this lecture he used his own sql library but I used sqlite3 library. But he said this function is in almost libraries.